# TypeError while INSERT'ing multiple instances into database using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

So I get an a list of list which contain employees info and I want to write it to database. SQLAlchemy documentation says its correct by, now but DB is still empty. Database was created properly, how I can now insert data from
employees_list to database ?

My code

```
from PyBambooHR import PyBambooHR
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import pprint


Base = declarative_base()


class EmployeeData(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'employee_data'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(120))
    department = Column(String(120))
    jobTitle = Column(String(120))
    email = Column(String(120))


engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///employee_db.db')

connection = engine.connect()


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

bamboo = PyBambooHR(subdomain='company', api_key='key')


employees = bamboo.get_employee_directory()
employees_list = [[item['displayName'], item['department'], item['jobTitle'], item['workEmail']] for item in employees]


employees_list.sort()

connection.execute(employees_list.insert())

connection.close()

pprint.pprint(employees_list)
```

causes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 37, in <module>
    connection.execute(employees_list.insert())
TypeError: insert() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

Comment: what `employees_list.insert()` supposed to do?

Comment: You should be seeing some errors, such as `TypeError: insert() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä yeah, i get it right now and i dont understand what i need to put here, im new at work with databaases

Comment: @AzatIbrakov it must add all data from employees_list to database

Comment: `list.insert` method has nothing to do with databases

Comment: @AzatIbrakov so how I can add my employees_list to employee_db ?

Comment: Your `employees_list` is an instance of `list`, so `employees_list.insert()` calls [`list.insert()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), not for example [`Table.insert()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.insert). You should reread the documentation, especially the tutorials, like this one: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements. Questions not unlike this have also been asked on this site many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current problem is that you are using [`list.insert`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method which has nothing to do with **SQLAlchemy**.

If you need to properly insert objects into database using **SQLAlchemy** you can open database [`Session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html), create `EmployeeData` instances, add them to session and commit changes.

To do so we can define `EmployeeData` initializer as follows

```
class EmployeeData(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee_data'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(120))
    department = Column(String(120))
    jobTitle = Column(String(120))
    email = Column(String(120))

    def __init__(self, name, department, jobTitle, email):
        self.name = name
        self.department = department
        self.jobTitle = jobTitle
        self.email = email
```

Open `Session`

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, sessionmaker
...
session_factory = sessionmaker(engine)
session = session_factory()
```

Create `EmployeeData` instances

```
employees_list = [EmployeeData(name=item['displayName'],
                               department=item['department'],
                               jobTitle=item['jobTitle'],
                               email=item['workEmail'])
                  for item in employees]
```

Add `EmployeeData` instances & commit changes

```
session.add_all(employees_list)
session.commit()
```

## Test

Since I don't have access to `Bamboo` service I'll imitate response

```
employees = [{'displayName': 'John Doe',
              'department': 'IT',
              'jobTitle': 'Python Developer',
              'workEmail': 'jdoe@company.com'}]
```

Following steps above I got `employee_db.db` **SQLite** database in my working directory. Let's open it using **SQLite CLI** (from [**SQLite** tools](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html))

```
sqlite> .open employee_db.db
sqlite> select * from employee_data;
1|John Doe|IT|Python Developer|jdoe@company.com
```

## Further reading

- [Session basics](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#session-basics).
- [Session API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html).